# How to get JavaDoc for SWT and JFace in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, javadoc, jface

I'm a newbie to Eclipse and can't figure out how to get the JavaDocs for SWT and JFace to show up when I am editing.

How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: for Juno, the location for jFace is http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/

Comment: @t3chi3: That link has rotted away; but see http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Plug-in_Development_FAQ#Where_do_I_find_the_javadoc_for_the_Eclipse_API_locally.3F_I_don.27t_always_want_to_load_stuff_up_in_a_browser for downloading the javadocs for view in a browser; for Eclipse installing the "Eclipse SDK" and the "Eclipse Platform SDK" through "Install New Software" helped.

Comment: U have not marked the correct answer as correct. Fabian Steeg's answer is the correct one. But it is bit unclear. I have described it more in my answer in case if anyone needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you've dowloaded the jars yourself and referenced them in your project. If so, you can right click the jar in the project explorer (in the 'Referenced Libraries' node) and click 'Properties'. The window that appears you can define the location of the jar's JavaDoc and source, if you have those available.

You can also reach this by clicking Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and expanding the node for the jar to which you want to add javadoc/source.

Also worth mentioning that if you use Maven (http://maven.apache.org/) for building your project, it's dependency management system will take care of finding sources and javadocs for you. But that's a different topic entirly. Also might be worth looking at Ivy (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) - similar dependency management system, but can be used without selling your soul to Maven, I'm told.

---

You might also mean that you can't actually see the javadocs: Window > Show View > Other... > Java > JavaDoc. This view will show you the javadoc for whatever is currently in focus. Or just mouse over a method to see the javadoc in a popup.

Answer (score 3):

Following the advice from ukulele, I was able to right click on the jar and set the javadoc location. In this case the location for the online javadoc was:

http://help.eclipse.org/stable/nftopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/

Found from the SWT website:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/docs.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Install the 'Eclipse SDK' if you want JavaDoc for everything(including plugins) installed in Eclipse. The update site for this is

```
download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4
```

(this is for eclipse juno. for kepler use version number 4.3 instead of 4.4)
Go to `Help > Install New Software...` and give the above url for "work with" section. Then you should select the "Eclipse SDK" and install it.
After the installation and restarring eclipse all the docs will be visible in your editor whenever you hover with mouse over a special keyword.
Trust me this is the easiest and 100% correct method.

For further clarification What will happen in this is it will configure the javadoc path for "org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.102.1.v20140206-1358.jar" and "org.eclipse.swt_3.102.1.v20140206-1334.jar"(or in windows org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_643.xxxx.jar) and  which are visible in plugin dependencies of the project structure appropriately. So to manually set the javadoc support right click project>Build path>configure build path>under libraries tab>plugin dependencies select the .jar related to the swt(for windows org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_643.xxxx.jar and for linux org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_xxxxxxx.jar) expand it and set the javadoc location. For the java doc location you should give the the archive path of org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_4.3.0.v20130606-0003.jar as "\Eclipse-Kepler\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv_4.3.2.v20140205-0929.jar" which is located in PATH_TO_ECLIPSE_FOLDER\eclipse\plugins (if this file is not there, u should put it there). U should give reference/api as the path within archive.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a "Plug-in Project" they are there by default. That project type is available in "Eclipse for RCP/Plug-in Developers" or "Eclipse Classic". If you have a different version, you should be able to set up such a project after installing the "Eclipse SDK" feature via the update manager (in 3.4 under Available Software -> The Eclipse Project Updates).

Answer (score 1):

I often find the javadoc at eclipse.org to be really really slow to load.
The javadocs may be included with your eclipse install and thus be available locally; try **Help->Help Contents** menu and search for 'SWT' to see if this is true on your installation.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to attach the SWT source jar (for example `org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64.source_3.7.0.v3735b.jar`) from the `eclipse/plugins` directory to the referenced library. You'll be able to view both the source and the Javadoc.

Found on [Eclipse Community Forums: Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT) » JavaDocs](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/557082/).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are developing with org.eclipse.jface.text, also edit the org.eclipse.jface.text jar's javadoc location to:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/