# Attaching javadoc to libraries

Tags: eclipse, javadoc

as an example, I'd like to attach the javadoc to org.eclipse.swt
As I've read in similar threads, I went to the build path, expanded the swt library node and tried to enter the url as the javadoc location:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/advanced/content.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/index.html

Trying to validate it however tells me that typical root files like package-list or index.html couldn't be found. Obviously pretty weird since the url ends with index.html. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify the URL for the javadocs if it has a package-list file. Otherwise you will have to use downloaded javadocs/src for the jar. Then you can do specify the location for those javadocs archives in the same window you tried. You can attached sources if you want to see the source instead of decompiled library classes. 
Similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566877/how-to-get-javadoc-for-swt-and-jface-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Do not include the index.html part at the end.  You want a URL to which you can append "package-list" and actually get the right content.

Comment: You mean help.eclipse.org/indigo/advanced/content.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/ ?
If I do that, it'll result in the same error, this time even instantly. Before it always took a couple of seconds. If I append package-list to this modify URL, I get the list though...